# should big mysql table be split, use merge engine, master/slave or something else?

Tags: mysql, performance, master-slave, large-data

I might have gone down the path of over optimizing too soon and gotten myself lost. I'm recording all the moves possible in a board game's game tree. I have little hope of completing the tree since it will get so big (10^28) but want to get a good chunk if possible. In anticipation of slow queries I split the tables into ~50 branches of the tree with suffixes describing each branch.

Unfortunately my application has lots of reads, writes, updates and joins so things got slow quickly before I split them up. Since then I've also added some very helpful indexes which might have solved initial sluggishness. However as the app develops it's getting more and more complicated to switch between so many tables with more complicated joins. I've recently heard about using a master slave set up as well as a merge engine to help with large tables. Did I choose the wrong solution to my problem or should I just stick it out?

Comment: You can use partitioning for your tables, if you dont want to change your application. if this case the index is created for each partition separat and you can also use it completed. You can also drop a partion i.e. with old data and so on see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partitioning-overview/

Comment: I would go down the Route Catus Kev did in his poker hand evaluator. http://suffe.cool/poker/evaluator.html  there may be that many unique moves, but are there that many distinct ? Cutting the data will be key.

Comment: Neither merge nor partitioning seem likely to be your friend in this case...  but what, exactly, are you storing (potentially) 10^28 of, and how is it being used?

Comment: Each record is a move made in a game of othello. I start by selecting a random move that has unexplored possible next moves and record a branch from that point. After recording each move on the way to the end i have to update the parent of my origin to update the number of unexplored next moves. It's depth first search but with random starting points to keep the resulting games varied. Otherwise pruning alone might be enough to keep the db small. Furthermore the finished games were going into another  database that i had split into branches, i think it was overkill and now i'm in a sea of db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10^28 rows or anything else, to put it bluntly, *impossible*.  Calculate the cost of that much disk space; that should scare you.  You need to focus on "pruning" your trees.

`PARTITIONing` looks tempting, but it does not inherently provide any performance benefit (with rare exceptions).  Ditto for manually partitioning into 50 tables.  `MERGE` is merely an old variant of `PARTITION`.  Replication might help for *read* scaling.  Sharding (splitting data across multiple machines) could help, but adds to the cost and complexity -- and still won't get you to 10^28 of anything.

If you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the queries, we can discuss optimization, bit, indexing, etc, techniques.  These may help you some.

Are you using 64-bit `BIGINT UNSIGNED` for keeping track of *some* things on an 8x8 board?  And using boolean arithmetic for manipulating them?  In some situations, this can significantly decrease the disk space, the number of queries needed, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Here's the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on one of the manually partitioned moves tables: http://pastebin.com/8TbZ4TZU
I reverted my manually partitioned games tables into a single game table that looks like this: http://pastebin.com/EQFmYmLW

Comment: Would the 64-bit `BIGINT UNSIGNED` be used for the primary ID? I haven't gotten numbers anywhere 10^28 yet and don't want to over optimize too soon, but would like to have a rough plan when numbers start getting large. I have also considered getting rid of an int ID since my moves column (although `varchar`) is unique. Maybe there is a way to convert the `varchar` into a unique int since they only use A-B & 1-8?

Comment: Use `SMALLINT` (2 bytes) and `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes) wherever practical -- to save space.  Use `UNSIGNED` in most situations.  The 64 columns `a1`..`h8` -- what do the `INTs` represent?

Comment: Don't have both `KEY(x)` and `KEY(x,y)`; the former is redundant and should be `DROPped`.  Since you have a `UNIQUE` key, it _probably_ should be the PK instead of `id` -- unless it is often long and joined from many places.  (More details, plz)

Comment: I suspect you don't fill in all of `a1..h8`, in which case, you should probably make another table.

Comment: How long did it take to populate those 3M rows?  It will take 1000 times that long before you hit the limit of `INT UNSIGNED`?

Comment: Roger on the `SMALLINT`, `MEDIUMINT` and `UNSIGNED` advice thank you. the 64 `INTs` should be `SMALLINT` they represent the final board state, either 0, 1 or 2. I wanted to be able to run queries to check for symmetry like `WHERE A1=A8, B1=B8, etc`. I could move them into a joined table since they're hardly used that way, or is it possible to make a similar call using `REGEXP` or `LIKE` or `RLIKE`? anyway not an important feature anymore.

Comment: Great to know about redundant keys. I thought the combo was important since the relevant query also includes both, should I instead have two separate indexes for each column, or just the one index for both?

Comment: the `UNIQUE` key is the sequence of moves that make up the game, maximum 60 moves written in Chess Notation so max 120 characters. It could be changed into an INT where letters are subbed for numbers but 120 digits is larger than `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. Most queries are on user_id but made on moves as well. I would love to order by modified but have given up hope because it slows everything so much.

Comment: Eh?  Isn't a "final board state" 2^64 different values.  That would need a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` with each bit indicating the color of the token on one of 8*8 squares.  And the "final" state would not have blank?  If it did, you would need 3^64 -- too big for any int.

Comment: Most of the 3M came from a tournament database and the rate of growth will probably not be very fast for some time, maybe another 3M in the next year. That means we've got 1,000 years to find a solution to the 10^28 problem!

Comment: @ "final board state": each column just represented one square on the final board so I could do those complicated column matching queries. some squares can get stranded and end up blank at the end of the game.

Comment: Indexing and keys [see my cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: `A8` is convenient, but takes 2 bytes.  A pair of 3-bit numbers is sufficient.  So it _could_ be squeezed into 60*6 bits - 45 bytes - `VARBINARY(45)`.  Or, more simply `VARBINARY(60)`using a whole byte for the 6 bits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115900/discussion-between-billybradley-and-rick-james).